# linux comando SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

Boa tarde,

Sou novato em comandos linux, preciso visualizar mais que um arquivo, atualmente consigo utilizar para visualizar 1 arquivo:

```
tail -f pasta/arquivo
```

Gostaria de estar visualizando 2 ou mais arquivos, algo como:

```
tail -f pasta/arquivo1 pasta/arquivo2 pasta/arquivo3
```

É possivel fazer algo desse tipo?

Comment: O exemplo que você deu funciona não? `tail -f arq1 arq2 arq_n`. Pelo menos no linux funciona, já no lixux eu não conheço mas deve ser semelhante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que tal:

```
tail -f file1 & tail -f file2
```

Ou:

```
tail -f file1 | sed 's/^/file1: /' &
tail -f file2 | sed 's/^/file2: /'
```